# Attempting to add for loop values to dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a For loop that will search each row of a text file for multiple regex values and store them in dictionary pairs to be written to a csv file.  I'm basically trying to store each line searched as its own dictionary value and ultimately write each dictionary pair to its own line in a csv using Pandas.  I am attempting to mirror code I located for searching a text file using multiple regexes.  When I run the code I located against a text file it works fine.  When I modify it with my code the dictionaries created include several none values.  I only want the found values.   I have been attempting to figure out what is different in my code.  I'm new to Python so any comments off topic to improve are also appreciated.

my code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

list1 = []

fh = open(r"test_data.txt", "r").read()
contents = fh.split()

for item in contents:
    list_dict = {}

    date_field = re.search(r"(\d{1})[/.-](\d{1})[/.-](\d{4})$", item)

    if date_field is not None:
        date = date_field.group()

    else:
        date = None
    list_dict["date"] = date

    time_field = re.search(r"(\d{1,2})[:](\d{2})[:](\d{2})$", item)
    if time_field is not None:
        time = time_field.group()
    else:
        time = None
    list_dict["time"] = time

    list1.append(list_dict)

print(list1)

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_csv("test_export_with_testdata.csv", index=False)
```

Output

```
[{'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': '2/5/2021', 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': '10:41:45'}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': '2/6/2021', 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': '10:42:45'}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': '2/7/2021', 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': '10:43:45'}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': '2/8/2021', 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': '10:44:45'}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}, {'date': None, 'time': None}]
```

Code that works from [www.dataquest.io](http://www.dataquest.io)

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import email

emails = []

fh = open(r"test_emails.txt", "r").read()

contents = re.split(r"From r",fh)
contents.pop(0)

for item in contents:
    emails_dict = {}

    sender = re.search(r"From:.*", item)

    if sender is not None:
        s_email = re.search(r"\w\S*@.*\w", sender.group())
        s_name = re.search(r":.*<", sender.group())
    else:
        s_email = None
        s_name = None

    if s_email is not None:
        sender_email = s_email.group()
    else:
        sender_email = None

    emails_dict["sender_email"] = sender_email

    if s_name is not None:
        sender_name = re.sub("\s*<", "", re.sub(":\s*", "", s_name.group()))
    else:
        sender_name = None

    emails_dict["sender_name"] = sender_name

    recipient = re.search(r"To:.*", item)

    if recipient is not None:
        r_email = re.search(r"\w\S*@.*\w", recipient.group())
        r_name = re.search(r":.*<", recipient.group())
    else:
        r_email = None
        r_name = None

    if r_email is not None:
        recipient_email = r_email.group()
    else:
        recipient_email = None
    emails_dict["recipient_email"] = recipient_email

    if r_name is not None:
        recipient_name = re.sub("s*<", "", re.sub(":s*", "", r_name.group()))
    else:
        recipient_name = None

    emails_dict["recipient_name"] = recipient_name

    date_field = re.search(r"Date:.*", item)

    if date_field is not None:
        date = re.search(r"\d+\s\w+\s\d+", date_field.group())
    else:
        date = None

    if date is not None:
        date_sent = date.group()
    else:
        date_sent = None

    emails_dict["date_sent"] = date_sent

    subject_field = re.search(r"Subject: .*", item)

    if subject_field is not None:
        subject = re.sub(r"Subject: ", "", subject_field.group())
    else:
        subject = None

    emails_dict["subject"] = subject

    # "item" substituted with "email content here" so full email not displayed.

    full_email = email.message_from_string(item)
    body = full_email.get_payload()
    emails_dict["email_body"] = "email body here"

    emails.append(emails_dict)
# Print number of dictionaries, and hence, emails, in the list.
print("Number of emails: " + str(len(emails_dict)))

print("n")

# Print first item in the emails list to see how it looks.
for key, value in emails[0].items():
    print(str(key) + ": " + str(emails[0][key]))

df = pd.DataFrame(emails)

df.to_csv("test_export.csv")
```